# Power Query compare Fiscal and Calendar data where companies have different fiscal years

Tags: date, dax, powerquery

I'm using Power Query analyse data on various companies. 100 companies, 2 sets of data are issued by the various companies based on their respective fiscal reporting periods, and covers the previous 12 months, and 1 set is calendar, covering previous 3 months (quarterly). I am comfortable to assume that the annual data can be aportioned evenly accross each quarter, and once this is done would like to combine 2 metrics ( their product)

Hopefully some example data helps:

```
CompanyScores
|company ID| Metric | Fiscal Year | Value|
|:---------|:-------|:------------|:----:|
|Company 1 |Metric1 | 2019        | 123  |
|Company 1 |Metric1 | 2020        | 234  |
|Company 1 |Metric1 | 2021        | 234  |
|Company 1 |Metric2 | 2019        | 456  |
|Company 1 |Metric2 | 2020        | 567  |
|Company 1 |Metric2 | 2021        | 567  |
|Company 2 ......
```

FiscalYearEndDatesv - note different companies have different fiscal year ends ( although always at the end of a quarter). They may occasionally also change their fiscal year end, but lets not go there now...

```
|company ID|  Fiscal Year | FYEnd|
|:---------|:-------------|:-----:|
|Company 1 | 2019         | 31/3/19|
|Company 1 | 2020        | 31/3/20|
|Company 2 | 2019         | 30/6/19|
|Company 1 | 2020        | 30/6/20|

Company Weights (using calendar dates)
|company ID|  Period Ending |Weight|
|:---------|:-------------|:-----:|
|Company 1 | 31/3/19      | 3%|
|Company 1 | 30/6/20       | 6%|
|Company 1 | 31/9/20 | 5%|
```

For any period ending the sum of all the company weights makes 100%.

1- I believe I need to expand the annual data series into quarterly data, giving each period 1/4 of the annual amount.

2- Then I need to lag the fiscal periods by a different amount depending on the company.

The result will be for say Company 1 with Fiscal year end 31/3/21

For 1st calendar Qtr 2020 value = 1/4 of value of fiscal 2020

For 2nd Calendar Qtr 2020 value = 1/4 of value of fiscal 2021

I'm afraid i don't know how to do either of these steps.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you have tried (?) but dividing by 4 over quarters is not difficult

Add column, custom column, that has the formula

```
= Table.FromList({"Q1", "Q2", "Q3", "Q4"}, null, {"Qtr"})
```

Click on the arrows atop the new column to expand rows and create duplicates of each row labeled with quarters.  Right click the value column and apply some random transform operation to it, like round. That gives you something like

```
= Table.TransformColumns(#"Expanded Custom",{{"Value", each Number.Round(_, 1), type number}})
```

Change the code to end with this instead

```
each _ / 4, type number}})
```

Sample overall code below

You would need to explain the next step better

```
let  Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table2"]}[Content],
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(Source, "Custom", each Table.FromList({"Q1", "Q2", "Q3", "Q4"}, null, {"Qtr"})),
#"Expanded Custom" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Added Custom", "Custom", {"Qtr"}, {"Qtr"}),
#"Divide" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Expanded Custom",{{"Value", each _ / 4, type number}})
in  #"Divide"
```